# mysql insert trigger error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I just moved to phymysql and i'm having problems in creating of a trigger. Below is my script

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAutoInsert AFTER INSERT ON profile
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DECLARE var1 INT;
    DECLARE var2 INT;
    DECLARE var3 CHAR(100);
    DECLARE var4 CHAR(100);
    DECLARE var5 CHAR(3);

    SELECT      profile_id,
                profile_id,
                fname,
                fname,
                fpage
        FROM    profile
        INTO    var1,
                var2,
                var3,
                var4,
                var5;

    IF  var5 = 'yes'
    THEN

        INSERT INTO fiends
                (req_id, resp_id, req_name, resp_name, fpage)
            VALUES
                (var1, var2, var3, var4, 'yes');

    END IF;

END
```

When i execute i get this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Any help will be my appreciated.

Comment: spencer7593 raised a good point which led me to delete my first answer. My questions for you are, What is the purpose of this trigger? and, Which database client are you using?

Comment: I think there are several issues. I addressed most of them in my answer. It's not specified what client you are using, how you are creating the trigger. Some GUI clients may have a "create trigger" editor that automatically handles the delimiters for you. I suggest you develop the trigger in stages. As a first stage, I'd recommend you start with a trigger with a nearly empty, do almost nothing, body. And then build from there.

Comment: As the next stage, you need to determine what it is your trigger is supposed to do. A comment line or two, stating the purpose of the trigger wouldn't hurt. Knowing what you want the trigger to do goes a long ways towards getting it written. From the answers, you can see that Gordon and I came away with very different ideas about what the trigger was attempting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to do this in MySQL uses `:=`:

```
SELECT var1 := profile_id,
       var2 := profile_id,
       var3 := fname,
       var4 := fname,
       var5 := fpage
FROM profile;
```

In my opinion, the `into` clause is there to be similar to Oracle.

That said, two things to note:

1. This seems to assume that `profile` has only one row.  Normally there would be a `where` clause.
2. You should name your variables with a prefix (say `v_`) so they are not confused with columns.

However, I would write this without the variables:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trgAutoInsert AFTER INSERT ON profile
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO fiends(req_id, resp_id, req_name, resp_name, fpage)
        SELECT profile_id, profile_id, fname, fname
        FROM profile p
        WHERE fpage = 'yes';
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This seems much simpler.  I am guessing that `yes` should be a string.

EDIT:

If you want the rows just inserted, use `new`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trgAutoInsert AFTER INSERT ON profile
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO fiends(req_id, resp_id, req_name, resp_name, fpage)
        SELECT new.profile_id, new.profile_id, new.fname, new.fname
        FROM dual
        WHERE new.fpage = 'yes';
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Seems like this has the potential to create a lot of duplicate rows in `fiends`. Nothing invalid with that,  But I suspect that in OP trigger, the `SELECT ... FROM profile` was OP attempt to get the values from the row that were just inserted.  I suspect what OP really wanted was .. :NEW.profile_id, :NEW.fname, :NEW.fpage.  But that's just a guess... the question doesn't specify the expected outcome when the trigger is fired.

Comment: Acckk... my Oracle is showing. I used colons in front of NEW. Of course, MySQL doesn't uses just `NEW.`, and not the Oracle style `:NEW.`. (I'm still curious why we're inserting into a table named `fiends`.  I suspect our profile is associated with our `friends`. And not all of my friends are fiends.

Comment: the second script works perfectly. it just inserts the newly inserted record on the profile table to the friends table. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is with the statement delimiter; I suspect that it's still set to the semicolon character.

Because the trigger contains semicolon characters, to get the "create trigger" statement to run as one unit, you need to change the delimiter to a string that doesn't occur anywhere within the "create trigger" statement

For example:

```
-- change the statement delimiter to something other than semicolon
DELIMITER $$

-- execute the "create trigger" statement containing semicolons
CREATE TRIGGER ...
BEGIN
    ... ;
    ... ; 
    IF ( ... ) THEN 
        ... ;
    END IF;
    ... ;
END$$
-- the occurrence of the $$ delimiter on the line above ends the statement

-- change the delimiter back to semicolon
DELIMITER ;
```

---

Also, I'm thinking a trigger is not allowed to select from the same table that was just inserted into. (I know that's a restriction of FOR EACH ROW triggers in Oracle; I'd have to consult the MySQL Reference Manual to be sure... there's a section on "restrictions on mysql stored programs", procedures are the most liberal, functions have the same restrictions as procedures, plus more, and triggers have the same restrictions as functions, plus more.

Also, when that trigger executes (if it is allowed to select from the same table), that SELECT statement is likely to return more than one row.  With `INTO` form, we're expecting at most one row to be returned.

If the intent is to reference the values of the row that was just inserted, and use those in an insert into another table `fiends` (or `friends`?)
use the form  **`NEW.column_name`** to reference the values

For example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER profile_ai 
AFTER INSERT ON profile
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ( NEW.fpage = 'yes' ) THEN
        -- are some of your friends fiends ?
        INSERT INTO fiends 
        ( req_id
        , resp_id
        , req_name
        , resp_name
        , fpage
        ) VALUES
        ( NEW.profile_id
        , NEW.profile_id
        , NEW.fname
        , NEW.fname
        , 'yes'
        );
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```